# Connect to headless Raspberry Pi over SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, installation, raspberry-pi, ip-address

I've been searching the interwebs for hours trying to find a way to configure my Raspberry Pi to connect to the LAN and enable `SSH`.

My problem is: the Pi seems to boot up (all the lights come on and go blinky), but it isn't showing up on the network. I have no monitor or keyboard for it, so the entire setup must be headless.

**What I've Tried:**

To check whether the Pi appears on the network, I mainly used the following command from a Linux box (my subnet gateway is `10.22.0.1`):

```
nmap -p 22 --open 10.22.*.*
```

I'm on a college campus so there are a large number of machines on the network, hence my checking port 22 (`SSH`) directly, which I understand to be enabled by default. (Apparently the default `SSH` and networking is a relatively new feature of Raspbian? Anyone care to shed light on this or how to double check?)

I've also tried setting a static IP as described here:
http://elinux.org/Configuring_a_Static_IP_address_on_your_Raspberry_Pi

In all cases, the Ethernet switch the Pi is plugged into shows an orange light for the port, and for other devices which connect successfully it shows a green light. I'm not sure what that means, but I suspect it means that the Pi isn't getting an IP address.

**More Details:**

- The Pi is running a fresh image of the latest version of `Raspbian
  Wheezy` (as of February 1, 2016).
- The Pi is a model B version (yes, I know it's old), but the OS is
  new.
- I am powering it with a 5V 1A wall adapter.
- I have used the Pi successfully in the past (like 4 years ago), and
  recently dug it out again with a fresh OS on an SD card.

Comment: UPDATE: I think I *finally* managed to get the static IP working by editing cmdline.txt in the /boot partition according to these instructions:
https://kushrami.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/how-to-start-raspberry-pi-without-screen/
However, SSH still seems to be unavailable. SSH command returns "connection refused" and nmap shows zero ports open. I'm beginning to question whether SSH really is on by default.

Comment: UPDATE RESOLVED: Well, it appears I had a hardware problem. I swapped out the SD Card for a fresh one and everything is working. For anyone in the future who is feeling as helpless as I was, here are a few points of advice: 1. To set static IP, edit cmdline.txt as describe in my other comment. 2. The Pi responds to pings fairly quickly, but it can take a while for it to start SSH (should be enabled by default). I kept thinking SSH wasn't working but actually it just takes a few minutes for that service to start, so be patient. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this myself. Turns out it was a faulty SD Card. Also, anyone who is able to ping the Pi but not SSH, just be patient. It took 3-5 minutes for SSH to start on my Pi on the initial boot.